# filter specific requests in spring rest

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I built a restful application using spring framework. it has following file structure:

```
reportapi
  -src
    -main
      -java
        -java files
      -webapp/WEB-INF
        -dispatcher-servlet.xml
        -web.xml
  -pom.xml
```

I had following api to performing activities

```
 1. /login                     (authenticate)

 2. /authenticate              (authenticate)

 3. /searchByMobileRation (Header Authtoken)

 4. /searchByAll          (Header Authtoken)

 5. /saveDocument         (Header Authtoken) 

 6. /dashboard            (No Header)
```

I want to filter only those requests with Header `"Authtoken".`

If I place filter tag in `web.xml`, all requests will goes to filter class.

I don't want to include Spring Security as of now.

Any suggestions

Comment: yes do servlet chaining based on the condition like you have "Authtoken" in header allow for chain.doFilter(request, response); or else leave it

Comment: pls provide example

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FlowFilter implements Filter 
{

 @Override
public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException 
{

}

@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final
FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
          String authToken=httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authtoken");
          if(null!=authToken)
          {
            chain.doFilter(mutableRequest, response); 
          }  
}

 @Override
public void destroy() {
}
}
```

use filter mapping in web.xml for this above class

Comment: I don't want to call filter for every request url. as i mentioned `I want to filter only those requests with Header "Authtoken"`.

Comment: sorry I don't know on that way to achieve by adding one more filter before this to filter the unwanted request to enter to this particular filter so that this filter don't check for the condition